# How do I pick a static/dynamic resource color in a color?

Tags: xamarin.forms, resourcedictionary

How do I select a static/dynamic resource color in a color like this?

```
<ResourceDictionary ...
  <Color x:Key="RedColor">#C3404D</Color>
  ...

  <Color>{StaticResource RedColor}</Color>
```

This is the code I have

```
<ResourceDictionary ...>
    <Color x:Key="PrimaryColor">#507EA9</Color>
    <Color x:Key="SecondaryColor">#A76FBB</Color>
    <Color x:Key="PrimaryDarkColor">#112951</Color>
    <Color x:Key="SecondaryDarkColor">#75428F</Color>
    <Color x:Key="GreenColor">#63B743</Color>
    <Color x:Key="RedColor">#C3404D</Color>

    <Style TargetType="chart:SfChart" x:Key="ChartPie1">
        <Setter Property="ColorModel">
            <Setter.Value>
                <chart:ChartColorCollection>
                    <Color>#507EA9</Color>
                    <Color>#A76FBB</Color>
                    <Color>#112951</Color>
                    <Color>#63B743</Color>
                    <Color>#75428F</Color>
                    <Color>#C3F3A0</Color>
                </chart:ChartColorCollection>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="chart:SfChart" x:Key="ChartPie2">
        <Setter Property="ColorModel">
            <Setter.Value>
                <chart:ChartColorCollection>
                    <Color>#75428F</Color>
                    <Color>#63B743</Color>
                    <Color>#A76FBB</Color>
                    <Color>#112951</Color>
                    <Color>#C3F3A0</Color>
                    <Color>#507EA9</Color>
                </chart:ChartColorCollection>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

I wonder if it is possible to not to have to define the colors over and over again? Just write something like:

```
<chart:ChartColorCollection>
    <Color>{StaticResource PrimaryColor}</Color>
    <Color>{StaticResource SecondaryColor}</Color>
    ...
</chart:ChartColorCollection>
```

Comment: What you mean by selecting color? Your code is incorrect. ResourceDictionary must have a key.

Comment: I want o get a color that is already defined to insert into a collection within the ResourceDictionary. I know the code is incorrect. Do I have to write the RGB code everytime or can I call the StaticResource somehow?

Comment: @lise-lotte, **I would like to don't have to write all the RGBs over and over again. Is it possible**, According to your description, I am not sure what you want to do, so can you provide some code here to describe detailed info?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment you can define colors in styles as static resource and reuse them in your code. Example:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml">

    <Color x:Key="PrimaryColor">#373749</Color>
    <Color x:Key="SecondaryColor">#45455c</Color>

    <Style x:Key="TitleLabelStyle" TargetType="Label">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20" />
        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource PrimaryColor}" />
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Then in your xaml you reference like this for example:

```
<StackLayout BackgroundColor="{StaticResource PrimaryColor}">
```

or style:

```
<Label Style="{StaticResource TitleLabelStyle}" />
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you but I don't think I've explained it properly. I have some styles like this:

    <Style ...>
        <Setter Property="ColorModel">
            <Setter.Value>
                <chart:ChartColorCollection>
                    <Color>#507EA9</Color>
                    <Color>#A76FBB</Color>
                    ...
                </chart:ChartColorCollection>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>    </Style>


I would like to don't have to write all the RGBs over and over again. Is it possible?

Comment: Why don't you reuse it like in example I provided?

Comment: Because I have a collection of colors to the target, not just one color. And I want to change colors when I change the theme later on.

I already use the way you said in other places.

Comment: Why not to use for example {StaticResource PrimaryColor} instead of defined color?